# LINQ to SQL - database relationships won't update after submit

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have a Database with the tables `Users` and `Uploads`. The important columns are:
`Users -> UserID`
`Uploads -> UploadID, UserID`
The primary key in the relationship is `Users -> UserID` and the foreign key is `Uploads -> UserID`.
In `LINQ to SQL`, I do the following operations:

```
Retrieve files
var upload = new Upload();
upload.UserID = user.UserID;
upload.UploadID = XXX;
db.Uploads.InsertOnSubmit(upload)
db.SubmitChanges();
```

If I do that and rerun the application (and the `db` object is re-built, of course) - if do something like this:

```
foreach(var upload in user.Uploads)
```

I get all the uploads with that user's ID. (like added in the previous example)
The problem is, that my application, after adding an upload an submitting changes, doesn't update the `user.Uploads` collection. i.e - I don't get the newly added uploads.

The `user` object is stored in the `Session` object. At first, I though that the `LINQ to SQL Framework` doesn't update the reference of the object, therefore I should simply "reset" the `user` object from a new `SQL` request. I mean this:

```
Session["user"] = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserID == user.UserID).SingleOrDefault();
```

(Where `user` is the previous user)
But it didn't help.
Please note: After rerunning the application, `user.Uploads` does have the new upload!
Did anyone experience this type of problem, or is it normal behavior? I am a newbie to this framework. I would gladly take any advice.

Thank you!
P.S I have a `DB.Uploads.Count()` line in another method, and it *does* increase after the addition of the upload.

Edit: Some things I have tried:

1. The first method in my code (initialization) is `db = new new DBDataContext();`.
   I've adding `db.Dispose; db = new DBDataContext();` after `db.SubmitChanges();` in my first method, just to see if it does anything. It didn't.
2. As a quick fix, I did `user.Uploads.Add(upload);`. It *does* add the appropriate object to `user.Uploads` which is then used in the `foreach` loop. Well, duh. But I am still waiting for some explanation about this behavior. Thank you!

Comment: try to add the `db.SubmitChanges()` after the foreach loop instead of inside

Comment: If you are going to retrieve the user from the database anyway, why bother with the Session object?  Also, `db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserID = user.UserID)`

Comment: I am sorry - the `db.SubmitChanges()` isn't in the `foreach` loop. The loop isn't in that method. The method which calls `SubmitChanges` is `Upload`, and another method has that foreach loop. Robert: How come? I need to check that. Thanks!

Comment: Robet, you might not have understood me. I am *NOT* retrieving the user from the database *everytime*. I just executed *once* - `Session["user"] = db.Where(...)` - and it *didn't* help - so I removed it.

Comment: Do you use the same context for all code? You should use only one or close the first and then open the second.

Comment: I do use the same context. I did a static one, I always use it.

Comment: Adding this code line `user.Uploads.Add(upload)` (without removing the `Uploads.InsertOnSubmit`) seems to fix this. I am still waiting for an answer with an explanation though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing the User object in the Session causes it to be disconnected from the data context on subsequent requests.  Thus, any changes made to the database (for the user entity or any of its child entities) will not be reflected in the object instance.

To deal this this, you have several options.  As you have done, you could simply update the Session-stored object instance yourself any time you make changes.  You could also reconnect the entity stored in the Session before making any database changes (which in itself can have issues).  You could also refresh the session object instance any time you change the data.  And finally, you could not store the object in the session at all, and just retrieve it from the database any time you need it.

You mention that you tried refreshing the stored session object and it didn't help.  I'm assuming you did this after calling `SubmitChanges()`, correct?  This should have worked.  Could you post the two methods in question (ie. the full method inserting the new upload and the method containing the `foreach` loop) and how they interact, please?

Comment: So you basically mean that the `user` object isn't *updated* by rebuilt. AKA by value, not by reference. Like I suspected. I believe that updating the object isn't the *best* way of doing it, but most efficient? Should I stick to it or try something else?

Comment: @QuanticProgramming It has nothing to do with by value/reference, and everything to do with the fact that your session-stored entity doesn't have a database context (ie. it knows nothing about the database, so can't be updated when the database is changed).  In terms of how to deal with this, it's really up to you and your overall codebase and design.  Personally, I avoid using the session like the plague, but if you do want/need to use it to store entities, you're going to have to manage updating those stored entities yourself.